# Cannot add test in Netbean C++ project with existing code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans, makefile

So, this is what I have done.

I had a c++ project that I imported in NetBeans. Since the code had its old makefile I made NetBeans use it. I then added the logical folder Test Files (and included cppunit libraries in its linker). If I now try to add a cpp unit test Netbeans complains that I do not have a Makefile and does not let me create the unit test.

The exact error message is:
Makefile is not detected. Test targets will not be added to makefile.

How should I modify my old makefile so that Netbeans will recognize it?

Thanks for the help,

Michele

**Additional information**
I followed the instruction in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/howto-add-unittests-ide-1731716.html#About on adding test to an unmanaged project but I cannot understand point 6. What should I add to my makefile? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: NetBeans and Oracle Solaris Studio might be different in details. What IDE do you actually use? What OS? Machine?

Comment: I use NetBeans but the instruction for netbeans are very similar and are written by the same person: http://nnnnnk.name/unittests/nb69unittests_for_existing.html

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project name in the `Projects` pane - you'll get a pop-up menu with first line `New`, place cursor on this line - another pop-up menu will be opened, left-click on the `CppUnit Test...` in this menu. You'll get a pop-up window with some settings you can adjust.

After you click `Finish` in this window the NetBeans will create a directory with test skeletons and add new targets to your Makefile.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Hekto, thanks for taking some time to answer me. This is what I did but in the create new c++ test menu, when I should be able to press Finish or Next, I get the error message Makefile is not detected. Test targets will not be added to makefile.

Do you know how to make NetBeans accept managed test in an unmanaged project?

Comment: @MicheleFG - What is unmanaged project? Do you have `Makefile` in the root dir of your project?

Comment: Unmanaged means, as far as I understand, that the makefile is not generated by NetBeans. My own makefile is in the root dir of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  It appears in NetBeans you MUST have the Test Package, which is where you would add your unit tests. If you create a C++ Application in NetBeans you will see the Test Package in your project.  If you have a project that uses a Makefile that was not generated by NetBeans, then it appears that there is no way to add this Test Package to your project.  I would be very happy to be wrong but this has been my experience and from all I have read it appears to be true.